# lhash crashes on lh_insert in C - Linux?

Tags: c, linux, openssl

I am trying to compile a sample program to use lhash. I can't see a good tutorial on lhash. So, my only way to understand lhash is by using lhash linux man pages. Here is the example, I am trying to make. However,I get a crash while doing the lh_insert. I am clueless on why is it happening.

```
/** In order to compile this program do the following **/

/**  gcc lhastEx.c -lcrypto -o lhastEx.out **/

/** Install the openssl dev library on ubuntu by -- sudo apt-get install libssl-dev **/
/*** This is needed for library hash -- basically open ssl ones **/
#include <openssl/lhash.h>

/** Hash table -- just like maps in C++ i.e. QMAP -- it needs a key and the value **/

/*I have got a prints to check the flow */
#define __DBG (1)

static void dbgMsg(const char *msg)
{
#if __DBG
   printf("%s",msg);
#endif 
}


static int cmpFunc(const void *src, const void *dest)
{
    dbgMsg("cmpFunc called..\r\n");

    const int *obj1 = src;
    const int *obj2 = dest;

    return memcmp(obj1, obj2, sizeof(int));

}

static unsigned long keyHash(const void *entry)
{
    unsigned long int hash = 0;
    const int *val = entry;
    dbgMsg("keyHash method invoked\r\n");

    hash |= *(val);

    return hash;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int *hashKey2 = malloc(sizeof(int));

   int *hashKey3 = malloc(sizeof(int));

   int *hashKey1 = malloc(sizeof(int));

   *hashKey1 = 10;
   *hashKey2 = 20;
   *hashKey3 = 30;

   /* we can make a function to generate this key unique **/
   /** Ideally, this 1 should be a unique hash value **/

    /************** Created the hash table now -- I see this as equivalent to the map in C ++ or QtMap **/   
    LHASH_OF(int) *hashtable = lh_new(keyHash, cmpFunc);
   /*** add a new entry now **/


   lh_insert(hashtable, hashKey2);


  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHASH API can be used (somewhat) similar to the [STACK API](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/STACK_API). Additionally, there is also the OpenSSL source code that can help you learn about it. For example, see `crypto/err/err.c` which uses a hash table of `ERR_STRING_DATA` and see `lhash.h` and `safestack.h` for the macro definitions.

The safest approach is to define strongly-typed functions for your table. In that case, one key aspect is the fact that the elements in your hash table have to be of a struct type. See the code below for an example how it could work for a hash table of integers, by using a struct with a single int field.

```
#include <openssl/lhash.h>
#include <string.h>

#define __DBG (1)

static void dbgMsg(const char *msg)
{
#if __DBG
    printf("%s", msg);
#endif 
}

typedef struct int_value_st {
    int value;
} INT_VALUE;

static int int_value_cmp(const INT_VALUE *a, const INT_VALUE *b)
{
    dbgMsg("cmpFunc called..\r\n");
    return a->value - b->value;
}
static IMPLEMENT_LHASH_COMP_FN(int_value, INT_VALUE);

static unsigned long int_value_hash(const INT_VALUE *entry)
{
    unsigned long int hash = 0;
    dbgMsg("keyHash method invoked\r\n");

    hash |= entry->value;

    return hash;
}
static IMPLEMENT_LHASH_HASH_FN(int_value, INT_VALUE);

/* See stack/safestack.h for a complete list of the possible #defines */
#define lh_INT_VALUE_new() LHM_lh_new(INT_VALUE,int_value)
#define lh_INT_VALUE_insert(lh,inst) LHM_lh_insert(INT_VALUE,lh,inst)
#define lh_INT_VALUE_retrieve(lh,inst) LHM_lh_retrieve(INT_VALUE,lh,inst)
#define lh_INT_VALUE_delete(lh,inst) LHM_lh_delete(INT_VALUE,lh,inst)
#define lh_INT_VALUE_free(lh) LHM_lh_free(INT_VALUE,lh)

int LHashTest(void)
{
    DECLARE_LHASH_OF(INT_VALUE);

    INT_VALUE *hashKey1 = OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(*hashKey1));
    INT_VALUE *hashKey2 = OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(*hashKey2));
    INT_VALUE *hashKey3 = OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(*hashKey3));
    INT_VALUE *hashKeyFound = NULL;

    hashKey1->value = 10;
    hashKey2->value = 20;
    hashKey3->value = 30;

    LHASH_OF(INT_VALUE) *hashtable = NULL;
    hashtable = lh_INT_VALUE_new();
    lh_INT_VALUE_insert(hashtable, hashKey1);
    lh_INT_VALUE_insert(hashtable, hashKey2);
    lh_INT_VALUE_insert(hashtable, hashKey3);

    /* Should find result */
    hashKeyFound = lh_INT_VALUE_retrieve(hashtable, hashKey2);
    lh_INT_VALUE_delete(hashtable, hashKeyFound);
    /* Should not find result */
    hashKeyFound = lh_INT_VALUE_retrieve(hashtable, hashKey2);

    /* OPENSSL_free()s all elements */
    lh_INT_VALUE_free(hashtable);

    return 1;
}
```

By the way, it looks like you ignored a few compiler warnings... that is usually not a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that this is due to the backward incompatible version of open-ssl. Here was the correction -

```
  _LHASH *hashtable = lh_new(keyHash, cmpFunc);
```

It just works very well. Here is the entire code now. This might help some new person trying his hand on lhash. Although, I think C++ gives more cleaner way of hashing rather than C. I didn't like this library. However, it is used in old projects.

```
/** In order to compile this program do the following **/

/**  gcc lhastEx.c -lcrypto -o lhastEx.out **/

/** Install the openssl dev library on ubuntu by -- sudo apt-get install libssl-dev **/
/*** This is needed for library hash -- basically open ssl ones **/
#include <openssl/lhash.h>

/** Hash table -- just like maps in C++ i.e. QMAP -- it needs a key and the value **/

/*I have got a prints to check the flow */
#define __DBG (1)

static void dbgMsg(const char *msg)
{
#if __DBG
   printf("%s",msg);
#endif 
}


static int cmpFunc(const void *src, const void *dest)
{
    dbgMsg("cmpFunc called..\r\n");

    const int *obj1 = src;
    const int *obj2 = dest;

    return memcmp(obj1, obj2, sizeof(int));

}

static unsigned long keyHash(const void *entry)
{
    unsigned long int hash = 0;
    const int *val = entry;
    dbgMsg("keyHash method invoked\r\n");

    hash |= *(val);

    return hash;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int inputBucket = 0;
   int *hashKey2 = malloc(sizeof(int));

   int *hashKey3 = malloc(sizeof(int));

   int *hashKey1 = malloc(sizeof(int));

   *hashKey1 = 10;
   *hashKey2 = 20;
   *hashKey3 = 30;

   int *ptrInputBucket = &inputBucket;

   /* we can make a function to generate this key unique **/
   /** Ideally, this 1 should be a unique hash value **/

    /************** Created the hash table now -- I see this as equivalent to the map in C ++ or QtMap **/   
    _LHASH *hashtable = lh_new(keyHash, cmpFunc);
   /*** add a new entry now **/

   lh_insert(hashtable, hashKey2);
   lh_insert(hashtable, hashKey3);

   /** now retrieve the data **/
   ptrInputBucket = lh_retrieve(hashtable, hashKey2);

   if( ptrInputBucket != NULL )
    {
       printf("The value retrieve from Hash Table is %d\r\n", *ptrInputBucket);
    }
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Good to see you that you found an approach. Note that there is a risk associated with this though: you are using essentially the "untyped" version of the hash table. This means that the compiler would not prevent you from inserting wrongly typed variables into your table. In case you are interested, I have included an answer if you want to do a strongly typed version.